# Silent server side authentication process with the username and password to Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

we need a way to do a silent server side authentication process with the username and password already in hand.

That is, our mobile application (Javascript) that makes a web call to PHP server.  That PHP server, in turn, calls our .NET Web Service.  That web service needs to make a SILENT authentication call to Azure AD (via oAuth or some other method).

What are our options?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25777676/310446

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible via the OAuth 2.0 [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) flow. However, I strongly urge you to think long and hard about whether this is the best and most secure approach. To cite the OAuth 2.0 RFC (emphasis added):

> The resource owner password credentials (i.e., username and password) can be used directly as an authorization grant to obtain an access token.  The credentials should only be used when there is a high degree of trust between the resource owner and the client (e.g., the client is part of the device operating system or a highly privileged application), **and when other authorization grant types are not available (such as an authorization code)**.

To see it in action, I'd recommend taking a look at the following sample: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-Headless-DotNet

(Even if you're not using .NET, running the sample and looking at the Fiddler trace will give you a good idea of what's happening.)